# How can I remove VML margins?

Tags: html, css, web, outlook, vml

I am trying to prepare a newsletter for Outlook and I have set the footer background color with VML. The code is something like this:

```
<container class="footermail"> 
<!--[if gte mso 9]> 
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:580px;height:141px;"> 
    <v:fill type="tile" color="#333333" /> 
<![endif]--> 
    <p>blablablablabla</p>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
</container>
```

The problem is, when I open the mail by Outlook for desktop (specifically 2106), it shows margins around it. Here's a pic:

[image: mail view]

Does anyone knows how to remove them? I have tried everything and searched for info but it is getting pretty hard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook in general does not really support HTML 5. Your issue is not so much the vml but with this tag: `<container class="footermail">`

You don't include your full code and CSS, so it makes it hard to diagnose all of your potential issues.

My suggestion is to remove the `<container>` tag and use a `<table>` instead with a background color. Something like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" style="background: #333333; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
  <tr>
    <td style="background: #333333;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <p style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">blablablablabla</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This table works in every major email client and every version of Outlook. Although it's a bit scrunched in Gmail for Android v4.

Outlook has a LOT of limitations. I suggest keeping this handy for future html emails. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck.